# flutter how to make electrical-like animation

Tags: flutter, animation

I have a gif demonstrating electrical-like animation

[image: Electrical-like animation]

The full gif is here: https://pin.it/3RGDs7W

Anyone knows how can implement this kind of animation on Flutter or I have to have a sequence of images to animate it

Answer (score 1):

The most feasible method is to use this gif in Stack below the button. Creating an animation like this is very difficult and also it will decrease the screen FPS and consume more resource. The other way I can think of is creating this animation on rive.app but this will also take a very long time and you will have to learn how to create animations on rive.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I know it's very difficult to implement by code. I have to find some designer to make it.